# Is it possible to compare a value with a collection attribute in a where clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

So, I have three tables: 'cars', 'hotlaptimes' and 'tyrestemperature'. Lets say I'm sensing the tyres temperature in real time. I want to show in a view the best hot lap time, and the avg tyres temperature of that hot lap. I still can't find a solution to get the collection of tyre temperatures. Table 'cars' is the "father", with a 'cars_id' field on 'hotlaptimes' and 'tyrestemperature'. The models:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cars";

        public function hotlaptimes(){
           return $this->hasMany('App\Hotlap');
        }
        public function tyrestemperature(){
           return $this->hasMany('App\Tyretemp');
        }
} 
class Hotlap extends Model
{
    protected $table = "hotlaptimes";
    public function car(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
    }
}
class Tyretemp extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tyrestemperature";
    public function car(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Car');
    }
}
```

This is my closest approach on the controller:

```
        $car = Car::with(['hotlaptimes' => function ($query){
            $query->min('time');
        }])->get(['id']);

        $temperature = Tyretemp::where('cars_id',$car->id);
```

It gets me an error saying that Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

I'm sure it's not impossible, I must be missing something. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you are calling `get` that returns a collection (a container that can have many results) .. it does not have an `id` property ... the items it contains might have `id` properties though

Comment: what happens when you `dd($car)`? What do you get and also change `get(['id'])` to `get()` just to see whats going on

Comment: @usrNotFound I've tried that already, if I call dd($car) without trying to call $temperature, I actually retrieve the correct id, if I call an empty get() I get all the attributes. The problem is when I try to call $temperature.

Comment: @lagbox Ok I'm not following you haha

Comment: you are asking for a collection ... a collection is a fancy object wrapper around an array .. if you had an array filled with your models would you try and get the id from the array? or would you try and get the id from one of the models inside the array?  :)

Comment: are you just trying to get 'one' `Car` record? so you can get one `id` value?

Comment: your foreign key should probably be `car_id` .. your methods are named `car` which will make eloquent want to look for key `car_id` unless you override the convention on those relationship definitions for the `belongsTo`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show in a view the best hot lap time, and the avg tyres temperature of that hot lap.

If you are trying to retrieve the `car` with the `best hot lap time` this is how you approach it:

```
$best_hot_lap = Hotlap::with("car")
                    ->orderBy("time", "ASC")
                    ->groupBy("cars_id")
                    ->first();
```

Then you can either simply use the `cars_id` attribute of `best_hot_lap` to retrieve `Tyretemp`

```
$temp = Tyretemp::where("cars_id", $best_hot_lap->cars_id)->get();
```

Or use the `Car` relationship in your `Hotlap` model

```
$temp = $best_hot_lap->car->tyrestemperature;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just using eager loading? There is a section in the laravel documentation under "Relationships".
I can't test right now, had only small break, but maybe try something like

```
$bestlap = Hotlap::with('car.tyrestemperature')->sortBy('time')->first();
dump($bestlap->car->tyrestemperature->avg('temperature'));
```

It should load the best lap and eagerload the corresponding car and tyrestemperatures

Edit
I just realised you only want the temperature, not the lap...

```
Temperature::where('car_id', function($query) {
    return $query->select('car_id')->from(with(new Hotlap())->getTable())->sortBy('time')->first();
})->get();
```

This will get a collection of temperatures with the car_id that we will get by getting the car_id (the select part) of the first entry of the hotlap table sorted by time.
I guess you can work the average in there by yourself.